# Unable to load Private key when convert dsa certificate from DER format to PEM format using openssl

Tags: openssl, private-key, pem, der, format-conversion

I want to check a DER format dsa certificate is valid or not, so I try to convert it to PEM format using openssl.

```
openssl dsa -in 512b-dsa-example-cert.der -inform der -outform -pem -out 512b-dsa-example-cert.pem
```

Both files can be download from [here](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.htm), part 1.2.

The above command can work with rsa. But when I came to dsa, it say:

```
Unable to load private key
```

How can I pass the "Private key" to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to convert it from DER to PEM format then you can convert it as a x509 certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in 512b-dsa-example-cert.der -inform DER -outform PEM -out 512b-dsa-example-cert.pem
```

Comment: Thank you. I waste a morning with "dsa" parameter. Now I know that it only used for KEY, not for certificate.